# Record audio from two input device at the same time and save into wave file?

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm trying to record audio on two different devices at the same time and the output of the file should be saved in a wave file

Using NAudio I tried to solve the problem as shown below, but still I'm  not getting it

```
WaveInEvent waveSource1 = new WaveInEvent();
waveSource1.DeviceNumber = DeviceID1;
waveSource1.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 2);
waveSource1.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveSource_DataAvailable);
string tempFile1 = (@"C:\Users\Nirmalkumar\Desktop\speech1.wav");
waveFile1 = new WaveFileWriter(tempFile1, waveSource1.WaveFormat);
waveSource.StartRecording();
waveSource1.StartRecording();
Console.Beep();
int milliseconds = 5000;
Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);

waveSource.StopRecording();
waveSource1.StopRecording();
```

this is first wavesource

```
WaveInEvent waveSource = new WaveInEvent();
    waveSource.DeviceNumber = DeviceID;
    waveSource.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 16, 2);
    waveSource.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveSource_DataAvailable);
    string tempFile = (@"C:\Users\Nirmalkumar\Desktop\speech.wav");
    waveFile = new WaveFileWriter(tempFile, waveSource.WaveFormat);

static void waveSource_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
{
    waveFile.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);

}
```

Comment: can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: added the code.

Comment: Is that all the code? You haven't shown where you created `wavesource`. We can only see where you've created `wavesource1`.  Would also help if you describe what you're 'not getting'. Are you seeing errors, or ... ?

Comment: yes receiving same audio on both files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with naudio, but...

It looks like both your wavesources are using the same `dataAvailable` event handler. That means no matter whether `source` or `source1` receives audio it will end up writing the data to the same file.

One way to fix this is to separate them out, so each has its own event handler, and each then writes to a unique file

```
WaveInEvent waveSource = new WaveInEvent();
...
waveSource.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveSource_DataAvailable);
string tempFile = (@"C:\Users\Nirmalkumar\Desktop\speech.wav");
waveFile = new WaveFileWriter(tempFile, waveSource.WaveFormat);

WaveInEvent waveSource1 = new WaveInEvent();
...
waveSource1.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveSource1_DataAvailable);
string tempFile1 = (@"C:\Users\Nirmalkumar\Desktop\speech1.wav");
waveFile1 = new WaveFileWriter(tempFile1, waveSource1.WaveFormat);
```

Then your event handlers:

```
static void waveSource_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
{
    waveFile.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
}

static void waveSource1_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
{
    waveFile1.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
}
```